# why the div hide while drag it below or down in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make custom plugin in angular js .I am trying to use jquery drag plugin here in angular js .In below example when user draw below it is not hiding .please use given example
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

But.
when I use this plugin in my code .When user drag the div below or down or bottom side it hide why ?
here is my code 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXxmQK

```
    var app=angular.module("ionicApp",['ionic']);
app.directive('draggable',function(){    
        return{
            restrict:'A',
            scope:{

            },
            link:function(scope,element,attr){

                $(element).draggable();
            }
        }
    })
    app.controller('cnt',function($scope){

    })
```

[image]

please check out it is hide when drag at bottom

Comment: increase the height of the body tag

Comment: wait trying ..I will update you

Comment: @PallaviSharma , see this http://codepen.io/jigardafda/pen/QbNYPO. it was happening because of ionic css